# Error selecting Id and Name from dropdownlist selectitems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I have this `class` that I pass to a view:

```
public class CreateBatchViewModel
{
    private readonly List<GenericIdNameType> lines;

    public bool IsWizard { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LineItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(lines, "Id", "Name"); }
    }

    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }

    public string ProductionOrderName { get; set; }

    public List<Data.Batch> Batches { get; set; }

    public CreateBatchViewModel(bool isWizard) : this()
    {
        IsWizard = isWizard;
    }

    public CreateBatchViewModel()
    {
        lines = new List<GenericIdNameType>();
    }

    public CreateBatchViewModel(List<Data.Line> dataLines, bool isWizard)
    {
        IsWizard = isWizard;

        if (dataLines == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataLines");

        lines = new List<GenericIdNameType>(dataLines.Count);

        GenericIdNameType genericType = new GenericIdNameType()
        {
            Id = null,
            Name = Resources.Resources.CreateBatchViewModelDontHave
        };

        lines.Add(genericType);

        foreach (Data.Line line in dataLines)
        {
            genericType = new GenericIdNameType()
            {
                Id = line.LineId.ToString(),
                Name = line.Name
            };

            lines.Add(genericType);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I use the `LineItems` in the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Batches[index].LineId, new SelectList(Model.LineItems, "Id", "Name", Model.Batches[index].LineId))
```

But I get this error message:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the
>   name 'Id'.'

I don't understand it because I have an `Id` and `Name` (`get { return new SelectList(lines, "Id", "Name"); }`)

These are the fields of `SelectItems`:
[image]

I have tried to remove `Id` and `name` from the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Batches[index].LineId, new SelectList(Model.LineItems, Model.Batches[index].LineId))
```

But now it shows `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` in the Select.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LineItems` property is typeof `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and `SelectListItem` contains properties `Value` and `Text`.

Change the view code to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Batches[index].LineId, 
    new SelectList(Model.LineItems, "Value", "Text", Model.Batches[index].LineId))
```

or change the property to `IEnumerable<Line> LineItems` and do not create a `SelectList` in the method and keep your existing view code

Answer (score 2):

Well, the SelectListItem does not, per se, containt the property Id. It is a Key--Value relation where you can consider Text to be the Key.
Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx).
Basically, I guess you want to do something like this:

```
var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var productionOrder in ProductionOrders){
selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = productionOrder.Id,
                    Text = productionOrder.Name
                })}
```

In the controller and then send selectListItems and a property for the selected item's Id into your model (viewmodel).
Then you can simply do this in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedListItemId, Model.SelectListItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Which will then end up with the id of the dropdown to be your id and the displayed name to be your name.